# Multiple Raster Boxplots in R

Tags: r, raster, boxplot, r-raster

I am trying to make a figure that has a boxplot for 14 different rasters. Each raster represents the snow depth surface for a given 100m elevation band, from 1300-2600 masl. I know how to make a boxplot for each raster individually, but cannot figure out how to get all 14 onto the same figure. It would be ideal to skip converting the rasters to ASCII grids as has been previously suggested to me. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I for one have no idea what a "raster boxplot" is supposed to look like or what information it might display. So you should post an example of your successful creation of a single "raster boxplot" and then say what you expect in an arrangement of multiple ones, along with data suitable for constructing an example with three or four.

Comment: By raster boxplot I meant a boxplot generated from raster data. The person who commented below provided me with the code I was looking for. I will be more descriptive with future posts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
r1 = raster(vals=rnorm(100,2), ncols=10, nrows=10)
r2 = raster(vals=rnorm(100,5,2), ncols=10, nrows=10)
r3 = raster(vals=rnorm(100,4), ncols=10, nrows=10)
boxplot(data.frame(r1=values(r1), r2=values(r2), r3=values(r3)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You can use the `boxplot` method for `RasterStack` directly. First, `s <- stack(r1, r2, r3)` and then `boxplot(s)`.